# New host key while EC2 server is turned off

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2, public-key, filezilla

I have a server on EC2 that I was connecting to through FileZilla SFTP. Suddenly its asking me to trust a new host key. Even when the machine is turned off. Is this a man in the middle attack? How would it send a new host key if the machine is off?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that your instance IP address has changed (e.g. due to a restart) and your original IP address was assigned to a different instance.

That would explain both the different host key and the fact you can connect, despite your instance being off.